# switch-case performance in ECMAscript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, v8, ecmascript-5, spidermonkey

I'm using `switch-case` statements on regular bases in ECMAscript. Beside my personal endorsement about it, there is tons of specialist literature out, about performance in this language in general and about *conditional* statements specifically.

One good example I remember for instance, is the excellent book "*High Performance Javascript*" by Nicholas Zakas. Like in many other books and articles, it is said that a `switch-case` statement is always faster than `if (else)` statements, when you're using more than *two* conditional cases.

In any *C-like* language I know of, a `switch-case` statement is nothing else than a binary-hash-map which, broken down again, is a chain of *jmp codes* in assembly. Have a good read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement)

However, after this foreword:

I had a discussion about the usage of *event handler functions* with my team and how we are going to deal with event types. Whether or not we are going to use an explicit *function* for any event, or if we should use one *big* function which handles multiple *event types*. Within that discussion, the performance question developed and we created a very basic, simple *jsPerf*:

http://jsperf.com/engine-context-data-caching-test/3

And I was pretty much shocked about the results and what I saw. Believing in these test-cases, the *order* of `case statements` is drastically important on the performance of execution. The difference between `long` and `longSlow` there, only is the *position* of the `case 'baz'` statement within the `switch` statement. Is this for real and reasonable?

Is there any chance I overlook something ? First, I thought well, maybe its not enough `case` statements and the interpreter will just create `if-else` conditions under the hood, so I increased the number without any change in results.

I just refuse to believe that ECMAscript engines like *V8* and *spidermonkey*, still don't optimize this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm referencing this source: http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html#sect2

**Use the if statement when:**

- There are no more than two discrete values for which to test.
- There are a large number of values that can be easily separated into ranges.

**Use the switch statement when:**

- There are more than two but fewer than 10 discrete values for which to test.
- There are no ranges for conditions because the values are nonlinear.

**Use array lookup when:**

- There are more than 10 values for which to test.
- The results of the conditions are single values rather than a number of actions to be taken.

Comment: Your answer is appreciated, but it doesn't answer the question at all. You should re-read the question and maybe provide an in-depth answer :)